# Split string with proper format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have one Table in my SQL Server Database like

```
Table1

 srno   Filepath      
   1     C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Files\File_1.70837292036d41139fcf8fa6b4997d3c.pdf
   2     File_2.pdf
   3     C:\File_3.pdf
   4     File_4.70837292036d41139fcf8fa6b4997d3c.pdf
   5      
   6     NULL
```

i want only srno, filename from this.

how can i get only filename through simple query?

Desired Output like

```
  srno    Filename
    1       File_1.pdf
    2       File_2.pdf
    3       File_3.pdf
    4       File_4.pdf
    5       
    6       NULL
```

I have one Query but it is not showing proper working with ( srno 1 and 4 ) only

```
Select srno, CASE WHEN LEN(CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(ISNULL(table1.Filepath,''))))= 1 THEN ISNULL(table1.Filepath,'') ELSE  REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ISNULL(table1.Filepath,'')), 1, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(ISNULL(table1.Filepath,'')))-1))  END  as Filename
```

Comment: Do you want File_1.70837292036d41139fcf8fa6b4997d3c.pdf to be File_1.pdf ??

Comment: @jyparask :  Yes, i Want only File_1.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the sting and search for the index of the first `\`. Then get the right of your column using this index.

```
SELECT RIGHT(Filename,PATINDEX('%\%',REVERSE(Filename))-1)
```

If you want to turn File_1.70837292036d41139fcf8fa6b4997d3c.pdf to File_1.pdf then you could try the following, though it might look uggly:

```
SELECT 
LEFT
(
    RIGHT
    (
        Filepath,
        CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%\%',REVERSE(Filepath)) > 0 
        THEN PATINDEX('%\%',REVERSE(Filepath))-1 
        ELSE LEN(Filepath) 
        END 
    ),
    CASE WHEN 
    PATINDEX
    (
        '%.%',
        RIGHT
        (
            Filepath,
            CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%\%',REVERSE(Filepath)) > 0 
            THEN PATINDEX('%\%',REVERSE(Filepath))-1 
            ELSE LEN(Filepath)  
            END
        )
    )>0
    THEN
    PATINDEX
    (
        '%.%',
        RIGHT
        (
            Filepath,
            CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%\%',REVERSE(Filepath)) > 0 
            THEN PATINDEX('%\%',REVERSE(Filepath))-1 
            ELSE LEN(Filepath)  
            END
        )
    )-1
    ELSE 0 END
)
+
RIGHT
(
    Filepath,
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%.%',REVERSE(Filepath)) > 0 
    THEN PATINDEX('%.%',REVERSE(Filepath)) 
    ELSE LEN(Filepath)  
    END
)
```

Comment: it is not give me proper output.

Comment: It certainly doesn't look nice, but it gives the right results. Let me know how it goes...

Comment: Good to know it helped, but i really don't like the looks of it. I haven't checked but it may be a performance overkill in big tables. I would also suggest creating a function with it so you may have a cleaner query.